# How to require package that are compatiable with PHP version?

Tags: php, composer-php, dependency-management

In composer.json I have dependencies on many PHP packages. I want for dependencies to resolve to packages, that are compatible with PHP 5.5, but still can be ran at PHP 7.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

In general, PHP is backward compatible, so you should be able to run your library on any newer version, so it should be enough for you to specify the lowest required version.

To specify the particular PHP version, use the [`platform`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) configuration directive:

```
{
    "name": "some/library",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "config":
        "platform": {
            "php": "5.5"
        }
    }
}
```